# The Geological make-up in my area

Tags: geology, regional-geology

I live in the Piedmont area of Virginia and only an hour and a half from the foothills of the Blue Ridge Mountains.  I recently found a number of what I believe to be petrified wood specimens.  There is also a lot of quartz in the area.  I am curious about the types of rocks, and other geological formations that may be found in my area.

Comment: type "Piedmont virginia geology" into google. The USGS also has geological maps and reports for every corner of the US so you can look up your area. https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/i2033, The "roadside geology" book series is also great and better for laymen, they have one for every state. Try "roadside geology of virginia"

Comment: John this would be plenty good as an answer, about as is, as it offers two useful sources it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Your local university likely has a small natural history museum in its geology department. These are generally free and filled with information regarding local geology. I'd start there.....and bring your rocks; the attendant might be able to help you find someone who can identify your rocks.

Answer (score 0):

The Roadside Geology of Virginia by Keith Frye is one of a series of books about geology in different states. It probably would be a good place to start to explore different geologic features.